# What is C# equivalent of SQL function STR?

Tags: c#, sql, double, substring

I have following code in SQL:

```
declare @test numeric(19,15)    = 219.37345462345234235
SELECT str(@test,9,9) -- 219.37345

declare @test numeric(19,15)    = 19.37345462345234235
SELECT str(@test,9,9) -- 19.373455

declare @test numeric(19,15)    = 9.3
SELECT str(@test,9,9) -- 9.3734546
```

How can I achieve this in C# say I have

```
double  d = 219.37345462345234235;
```

Required output should contain 9 characters whatever the input is as shown in following sample[image: Sample input output]

Following code snippet gives the result

```
public static string GetFormat(double quantity)
    {
        quantity = Math.Round(quantity,9-(Math.Truncate(quantity).ToString().Length));
        string customQuantity = quantity.ToString().PadRight(9, '0');

        if (customQuantity.Length > 9)
            customQuantity = customQuantity.Substring(0, 9);
        else if (customQuantity.Length == 9 && customQuantity.EndsWith("."))
            customQuantity = customQuantity.Substring(0, 8);

        return customQuantity; 
    }
```

Could this be implemented in better way??
Thanks

Comment: What about `Math.Round(value, 5);`?

Comment: There is no exact equivalent. Particularly, you'd have to handle the "**" case yourself.

Comment: Use `string.format()` or `value.tostring()`.

Comment: See this link : http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetCustomStringQuantity(double quantity)
    {
        string customQuantity ;
        quantity = Math.Round(quantity, 9 - ((int) Math.Log10(Math.Abs(quantity))+1),MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);            
        customQuantity = quantity.ToString();  
        customQuantity= (quantity %1==0)?(customQuantity+".").PadRight(9, '0'):customQuantity.PadRight(9, '0');            

        if (customQuantity.Length > 9)
            customQuantity = customQuantity.Substring(0, 9);
        else if (customQuantity.Length == 9 && customQuantity.EndsWith("."))
            customQuantity = customQuantity.Substring(0, 8);

        return customQuantity; 
    }
```

This works for me . But i am not sure if this is optimized code .